# My first simple sharepoint hosted app not displaying correctly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-hosted-app

1. I have configured app environment successfully as described in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515677/MyplusFirstplusSharepoint-HostedplusAppplusinplus)
2. I have created simple sharepoint hosted app in visual studio and deployed successfully on my sharepoint server 2013.
3. But app is not displaying correctly ie. without sharepoint styling. when i open developer tool then there are lots of errors. see below screen shots.

**App user interface:**

[image]

**Errors on app page:**

[image]

**I want app interface something like below :**

[image]

Should i need to configure something in my app? please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a **root site collection** for the same web application like this : `http://webapp:1001/` from Central Administration then refresh your page or re-deploy your app.

Comment: I'm not using any custom css or js. I just want default sharepoint styling for my app.

Comment: Try to create a **root site collection** for the same web application like this  : **http:///webapp:1001/** from Central Administration then refresh your page or re-deploy your app.

Comment: creating root site collection resolved my issue. now app showing as expected. thank a lot youssef. please update your answer as your above comment.

Comment: Can you tell me why the root site collection is required for  app showing correctly ?